# How to use tokenizer or split?

Tags: android, arraylist, split, addition, tokenize

I am trying to use either `tokenizer` or `split` in Java for Android, here is my code so far:

```
ArrayList<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> alphabet = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();

textList.add("abc|123");
textList.add("def|456");
```

But, how to do: `add abc, def -> ArrayList alphabet` and `add 123, 456 -> ArrayList numbers` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But before split check textList is contain "|"

```
for(int i = 0; i< textList.size(); i++){
  String[] arr = textList.get(i).spit("|");
  alphabet.add(arr[0]);
  numbers.add(arr[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String text : textList){
    String[] parts = text.split("|");
    String part1 = parts[0]; // abc, def
    String part2 = parts[1]; // 123, 456
    alphabet.add(part1);
    numbers.add(part2);
}
```